# Switching between view mode and edit mode in MVVM?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, mvvm

I am new to MVVM and I've decided to move on and start adopting it in my upcoming projects.

I have read this related question and answer, but I don't know how this would be implemented with MVVM.

I want all the views in my project to have 2 modes, Edit Mode and View Mode.
I don't want the user by default to see TextBoxes for all the fields, I rather want them to see TextBlocks (or set all the `TextBoxe`s' as `IsReadOnly` property to true (via style etc. you tell me..).

When the user opens up the entity it should usually be TextBlocks, Labels (or readonly TextBoxes) etc., and if he clicks "Edit" (if he has permission to), it should go Edit Mode, and all the fields' labels should be inverted to TextBoxes (RichTextBoxes etc., ComboBoxes or any other editable fields that are not just labels).

I am pretty sure I am not the only one having this issue, I would like to hear from the experts what is the most efficient way to switch between these modes in pure MVVM, and whether it's is common to declare two separate views for it.

Please refer me to a good article that explains how to do it (maybe it is done by Visual State?? IDK).

**UPDATE**
I want to know WHAT rather than HOW, my question is about the pattern, and is **should I separate Edit Mode
from View Mode at either the V or the VM?**
So please emphasize this detail in your answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `IsReadOnly` property for your text boxes and bind that to the "edit mode" property:

```
<TextBox .... IsReadOnly={Binding IsViewMode} ... />
```

Then in your view model:

```
public bool IsViewMode
{
    get { return _IsViewMode; }
    set
    {
        _IsViewMode= value;
        // Call NotifyPropertyChanged when the source property is updated.
        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsViewMode");
    }
}
```

`IsViewMode` defaults to `true` and is switched to `false` when the user clicks "edit". The binding will instantly make all the text boxes editable.

You could do the same for the other controls - though it will be the `IsEnabled` property you need to bind to in these cases - though you'd have greyed out controls.

To swap out text blocks and your controls you'll need to have both controls sharing the same location in a grid and their visibility controlled by the `IsViewMode` property via a pair of converters:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" ...
           Visiblity={Binding IsViewMode, Converter=DirectConverter} ... />
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" ...
          Visiblity={Binding IsViewMode, Converter=InvertedConverter} ... />
```

The direct converter is:

```
return IsViewMode ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
```

The inverted converter is:

```
return IsViewMode ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: And what about the other fields? I said I want some fields to invert to a DropDown, some to a slider, some to a date picker, whereas at the View Mode they are all simple TextBlocks/labels? And that's a very essential part to me.

Comment: @Shimmy - sorry, I missed that bit (don't know why). You can do the same for ComboBoxes, but it might be the `IsEnabled` property you need to bind to.

Comment: So you're basically saying I should make a common view for edit/view modes, having all controls declared one near the other setting the IsReadOnly or Visibility control to the IsViewMode on the VM (using BooleanToVisibility converter for controls to hide), is that right? **I've added some content to my question.**

Answer (score 3):

I think about it this way: the View is what it looks like, and the ViewModel is how it interacts with the user.  Since a readonly interface has substantially different behavior than a read/write interface, then there should be two different ViewModels.

Now I did created an edit ViewModel that inherited from a display ViewModel because I considered the editing functionality to be an extension of the display functionality.  This works for simple CRUD type applications where the user is directly editing fields without a lot of business logic.

On the other hand, if you have a more complicated business process (or workflow) that you're modelling, then typically the way you manipulate information is very different from the way you want to view it.  Therefore, I would generally separate the two ViewModels unless it was just CRUD.

Comment: Exactly, I am talking about CRUD. As I said I am new to MVVM and want to learn it. Can you refer me to a good article on how to implement a CRUD application the MVVM way? **My main problem is also the transitions between the different views.**

Comment: @Shimmy - I suggest [Advanced MVVM](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/advanced-mvvm/) by Josh Smith.  It's short, but very informative and you can get the source code.

Answer (score 3):

ChrisF's answer is fine if you want to go the IsReadOnly route.  If you want to go the TextBlock-to-TextBox route, though, the most efficient way is have a Control which switches its Template, via triggers, based on the value of an IsInEditMode or IsInViewModel property.

Answer (score 2):

Viewmodel: I would definitely keep just one viewmodel with a ViewMode property much as described in ChrisF's answer.  Separate ViewModels would just be inelegant.

View:  As I see it, you have at least three options, with various pros and cons.

1. Just readonly-ing all the controls, as suggested in the ChrisF's answer.  Pros: Simplest thing to do.  Cons: That is an ugly UI in my humble opinion.
2. Create seaparate display and edit controls in separate containers.  Bind visibility of the containers to ViewMode.  Pros: A more pleasing ui experience can be afforded here.  You can even animate the transitions from one to the other. Cons: Doubles the number of controls (could hurt performance for very large windows). Positioning the controls inside the two containers at exactly the same pixel positions can become a bit non-trivial in a fluid ui.
3. For every edit control in the xaml, position a display control right on top of it.  Bind visibility to the ViewMode property.  Pros:  No duplication of label controls at least, so slightly faster.  Cons:  Harder to get animation stuff  and other view tweaks right.

Edit:  In view of the clarification provided, I chose to replace the previous answer as it pretty much largely dealt with the how and not the what.

Comment: I've added some content to my question. I wouldn't declare it like this. I hate that the ViewModel knows that there is a Visibility enumeration... I would follow [ChrisF's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917047/switching-between-view-mode-and-edit-mode-in-mvvm/4917104#4917104) using BooleanToVisibilit/BooleanFlagSwitch converters etc. I just got my answer that View Mode and Edit Mode should NOT be separated anyway.

Comment: @Shimmy: I think that while the Display and Edit mode should belong to the same view class and bound to the same viewmodel, the controls for them should be separated for a better ui experience.  I have changed the answer to reflect the same.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with the view model knowing that there's such a thing as visibility.

Comment: @Robert, right, of course, I mean I don't want the view model to be specific for Visibility-dependent controls (and other controls to rely on the IsReadOnly, ITOH I don't want to have redundant props on the views.

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd implement an abstract base class for my view models that implemented `IEditableObject` and exposed appropriate commands for `BeginEdit`, `EndEdit`, and `CancelEdit`.  It might be that the actual implementations for those three methods would have to be up to the derived classes, but the commands could live in the base class.

In this approach, `EndEdit` updates the model with the current values of properties in the view model.

I'd also implement a boolean `IsEditing` property in the base class, for use in data triggers, so that if I want to switch between modes without (say) opening a modal dialog, I can just do it in a style.

As far as the visual design of the front-end goes, I find the idea that a read-only view is just an edit view with read-only controls is one that appeals primarily to programmers.  Generally speaking, if you're simply presenting an object to a user, the goal of that presentation is to provide the user with an informative, clear, and intuitive representation of the information in that object.  If you're letting the user edit an object, the goal of that presentation is to make the task of modifying all of the editable properties of the object as easy and clear as possible.

Those are two very different sets of goals.  For instance, while a person's sex, height, and weight might be important pieces of information for an application to collect, it's probably not all that important for the system to present that information to the user in most contexts.  It seems like a very natural thing to do if what you have in your head is that edit mode is just like display mode.  But if you're placing the needs of the user, and not the programmer, front and center, it may not be the right thing to do at all.